# open custom post type in popup window instead of page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts

I have this code in my functions.php, don't know what to do next??

```
function our_artist(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Artists',
        'singular_name' => 'Artist',
        'add_new' => 'Add Item',
        'all_item' => 'All Item',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_iten' => 'New Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'search_item' => 'Search',
        'not_found' => 'No Items found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Items found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt'
        ),
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'exclude_from_search' => false
    );
    register_post_type('artists',$args);

    
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'our_artist');

function arc_create_artist_cat_tax_rewrite() {
    register_taxonomy('artist_cat',array('artists'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => 'Artist Category',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'artist_cat' ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'arc_create_artist_cat_tax_rewrite', 0 );
```

Comment: Explain in detail what you want

Comment: I want to show custom post type to show in pop up window instead of opening another page for a post

Comment: Like... when visitors click on the post's link in an archive/search results? Are you developing this theme from scratch? Have you created any custom templates for this post type? When you say "popup" do you mean a completely new browser window, or do you mean a modal?

Comment: @asfaar this function hooks works on admin dashboard, Ok if you want to open in popup window like boot strape modal, using wp query in popup apply while loop then appeared post type content in popup.